# How to read correctly barcode generated from Barcode128

Tags: java, barcode-scanner

I create with iText library some barcode. So when I try to read these bar code from barcode reader not all barcode are ready correctly.

For example I have this barcode:

M-254, the barcode read M'254.

But if I try to read this barcode with ios Application this application ready M-254.

why is this happening?

This is the code that I use to create a Bar

```
Barcode128 codeEAN = new Barcode128();
codeEAN.setCode("M-254");
codeEAN.setGuardBars(false);
codeEAN.setBarHeight(40f); // great! but what about width???
codeEAN.setX(1f);
Image img = codeEAN.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
img.scaleAbsoluteWidth(90f);
```

Comment: What barcode reader are you using?

Comment: USB barcode reader to read barcode from PC. And I use a free app on the apple store to read barcode from my smartphone

Comment: What is the type/model of the barcode reader?

Answer (score 2):

As the app works correct, I don't think it's a problem of the barcode.

I think the barcode scanner you use with the PC is configured incorrect or the input language/font at the PC does not render the "-" symbol correctly.

Comment: I think that you answer is ok, but how can I change the configuration of the barcode reader?

Comment: That's why I asked for the model. Its different among the manufacturers/models. Maybe just using another editor to scan into on PC would work. Also check your language settings of the operating system (and switch to the locale your smartphone uses).